# "join" two list of dictionaries on Id

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists of dictionaries where both have the same "id" key but otherwise different data.

```
list1 = [{"id":1, "spam": 3, "eggs": 5}, {"id": 2, "spam": 5, "eggs": 7}]
list2 = [{"id":1, "knights": 5, "coconuts": 2}, {"id": 2, "knights": 3, "cocounts": 8}]
```

I know I can do a nested loop something like this (I know I can use *dict.update* as well, but just writing it out as an exampel):

```
for id in list1:
    for i in list2:
        if id['id'] == i['id]:
           id['knights'] = i['knights']
           id['coconuts'] = i['coconuts']
```

but can anyone tell me the more pythonic or quicker way to do this? matching two lists with millions of rows in each does not practically work this way.

**Expected result is:**

```
[{"id": 1, "spam": 3, "eggs": 5, "knights": 5, "coconuts": 2}, {"id": 2, "spam": 5, "eggs": 7, "knights": 3, "coconuts": 8}]
```

Comment: Where's `id['knights']` and `id['coconuts']` in **list1** ??

Comment: You've already received an excellent answer, but for future reference: you should include all of your code to have sufficient context for meaningful reviews. The code you've shown is both a snippet and pretty clearly hypothetical.

Answer (score 7):

To improve *time complexity* you must sometimes **trade-off** *space complexity*. It's known as [**`space-time tradeoff`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space%E2%80%93time_tradeoff)

You can transform `list1` into a dictionary where *key* is `id` and *value* is the dictionary itself.

```
list1 = {d['id']: d for d in list1}
# print(list1)
# {1: {'id': 1, 'spam': 3, 'eggs': 5, 'knights': 5, 'coconuts': 2},
#  2: {'id': 2, 'spam': 5, 'eggs': 7, 'knights': 3, 'coconuts': 8}}
```

Now, iterate through `list2` and update `list1` based on `id`

```
for d in list2:
    list1[d['id']].update(d)

#print(list1)
# {1: {'id': 1, 'spam': 3, 'eggs': 5, 'knights': 5, 'coconuts': 2},
#  2: {'id': 2, 'spam': 5, 'eggs': 7, 'knights': 3, 'coconuts': 8}}
```

Take [`dict.values()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) to get desired output

```
print(list(list1.values()))
# [{'id': 1, 'spam': 3, 'eggs': 5, 'knights': 5, 'coconuts': 2},
#  {'id': 2, 'spam': 5, 'eggs': 7, 'knights': 3, 'coconuts': 8}]
```

#### Dealing with *`Edge cases`*

The above approach fails when `list2` has an `id` which doesn't exist in `list1`. If that's the case then use this and you want to add that new `id` to output too. Using [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault)

```
# for example list2 is as below
# [{'id': 1, 'knights': 5, 'coconuts': 2},
#  {'id': 2, 'knights': 3, 'coconuts': 8},
#  {'id': 3, 'knight': 4, 'coconuts': 5}] -> new `id` that's not in `list1`

# Here we leverage on `dict.setdefault`

for d in list2:
    list1.setdefault(d['id'], dict()).update(d)

print(list1)
# {1: {'id': 1, 'spam': 3, 'eggs': 5, 'knights': 5, 'coconuts': 2},
#  2: {'id': 2, 'spam': 5, 'eggs': 7, 'knights': 3, 'coconuts': 8},
#  3: {'id': 3, 'knight': 4, 'coconuts': 5}}

# To get list of dicts use `list(list1.values())
```

In case you dont want to update with new `id`, we can resolve this using `if` block here.

```
for d in list2:
    if d['id'] in list1:
        list1[d['id']].update(d)
# {1: {'id': 1, 'spam': 3, 'eggs': 5, 'knights': 5, 'coconuts': 2},
#  2: {'id': 2, 'spam': 5, 'eggs': 7, 'knights': 3, 'coconuts': 8}}
# No `id` 3 present in output
```

#### Using libraries that support [*`vectorization`*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_programming)?

If you are working on millions of rows you can leverage on [**`pandas`**](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/) which has many vectorized operations. In your case we can use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(list1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list2)

# Now, you have to merge them on `id`

out = df1.merge(df2) 

#    id  spam  eggs  knights  coconuts
# 0   1     3     5        5         2
# 1   2     5     7        3         8
```

To get output as a list of dict you [`df.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with `orient` param set to `records`

```
out.to_dict(orient='records')

# [{'id': 1, 'spam': 3, 'eggs': 5, 'knights': 5, 'coconuts': 2},
#  {'id': 2, 'spam': 5, 'eggs': 7, 'knights': 3, 'coconuts': 8}]
```

If you want include new `id`s then set `how` param of `df.merge` to `'outer'` by default it's `'inner'`

```
df1.merge(df2, how='outer')

#    id  spam  eggs  knights  coconuts
# 0   1   3.0   5.0        5         2
# 1   2   5.0   7.0        3         8
# 2   3   NaN   NaN        4         5
```

---

#### Code Review

- #### Naming variables

  ```
  list1 = [...]
  list2 = [...]
  ```

  A new reader might not understand what's `list1` and `list2`. Name them so they make sense to everyone.

  ```
  current_users_details = [...]
  new_details = [...]
  ```

  This is just an example, name them accordingly. What I do is ask myself *what is it storing in the data-structure?*... *family member details*? then variable name is `family_members_details`, *user details* then `user_details`, *pi value*? then `PI_VALUE`... etc.
- #### Violation of `E231`

  ```
  list1 = [{"id":1, "spam": 3, "eggs": 5}, {"id": 2, "spam": 5, "eggs": 7}]
  list2 = [{"id":1, "knights": 5, "coconuts": 2}, {"id": 2, "knights": 3, "cocounts": 8}]
  ```

  The above lines use inconsistent use of spaces after **`:`**, `PEP-8` suggest add a space after **`:`**.
- #### Violation of `E501`

  ```
  list2 = [{"id":1, "knights": 5, "coconuts": 2}, {"id": 2, "knights": 3, "cocounts": 8}]
  ```

  Lines longer than 79 characters, `PEP-8` standard suggests to keep characters in a line <= **79**
- You have missing `'` here `if id['id'] == i['id]:`
- #### Reusability

  Make a function which takes both the lists and updates them.

  ```
  def update_details(current_details, to_update_with):
      """
      updates user details
      """

      details = {d['id']: d for d in current_details}
      for user in to_update_with:
          details[user['id']].update(user)
      return details
  ```

  Write a much better docstring `:P`

---

I suggest using [**`black`**](https://pypi.org/project/black/) python code formatter.

```
ch3ster@ch3ster:~$ black --line-length 79 your_file.py
```

#### Formatted code

Formatted your code using `black`.

```
list1 = [{"id": 1, "spam": 3, "eggs": 5}, {"id": 2, "spam": 5, "eggs": 7}]
list2 = [
    {"id": 1, "knights": 5, "coconuts": 2},
    {"id": 2, "knights": 3, "cocounts": 8},
]

for d in list2:
    list1[d["id"]].update(d)

print(list(list1.values())) # Equivalent to print([*list1.values()])
```